# Label only from first author

Tags: biblatex, author-number

With the following example, I tried to get a label only made of from the first author using `maxcitenames`. But unfortunately it seems not to work. Do I miss something?

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{smith1,
author={John Smith and Mike Someone},
title={The book with a very very very very very long title},
year={2005},
location={New York},
publisher={Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,%
            backend=biber,
            maxbibnames=99,
            maxcitenames=1,
            backref=true
            ]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{\jobname}
    \renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}
    \renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{}
    \DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{in={}}
    \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{in={}}
    \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
    \DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\begin{document}
\cite{smith1}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are looking for the option `maxalphanames`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{smith1,
author={John Smith and Mike Someone},
title={The book with a very very very very very long title},
year={2005},
location={New York},
publisher={Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,%
            backend=biber,
            maxnames=99,
            maxalphanames=1,            
            backref=true,
            ]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{\jobname}
    \renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}
    \renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{}
    \DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{in={}}
    \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{in={}}
    \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
    \DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\begin{document}
\cite{smith1}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can I use `maxalphanames` also with **bibtex** backend? or just with **biber**?

Comment: @thewaywewalk: No. It's only available with biber.