# Problem with citation multiple authors

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I need to cite a paper with multiple authors:

```
@article{DBLP:journals/tit/HammonsKCSS94,  
  author    = {A. Roger Jr. Hammons  and
               P. Vijay Kumar and
               A. Robert Calderbank and
               Neil J. A. Sloane and
               Patrick Sol{\'e}},  
  title     = {The Z$_{\mbox{4}}$-linearity of Kerdock, Preparata, Goethals,
               and related codes},  
  journal   = {IEEE Transactions on Information Theory},  
  volume    = {40},  
  number    = {2},  
  year      = {1994},  
  pages     = {301-319},  
  ee        = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/18.312154},  
  bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}  
}
```

But when I made the citation it appears as `[HKC+94]` and I want to be `[HKCSS94]`. can anyone help me?

Comment: Which bibliography style, and which document class, do you use? Separately, do use a citation management package such as `natbib`?

Comment: I am new using latex, i use report as document class,alpha as bibliography style and i dont use natbib

Comment: Thanks. The appearance of the entries in the References section is determined by the bibliography style -- the argument of the command `\bibliographystyle`. To have a chance to help you, we thus need to know which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: Would you mind making the question title more specific?

Comment: Could you also indicate if you're willing to allow any truncation of the number of authors' initials and, if so, from which number on truncation should be performed. (Your current bib style appears to be set to truncate lists of 5 or more authors to the first three authors' initials and a `+` symbol.)

Comment: I would like to not be any truncation on the number os authors´ initials

Comment: @Dimitri - So, even if you have a piece with seven or nine authors, you still don't want any truncation? *Please*, do tell us which bibliography style you employ. Without that information, it's not possible to provide concrete advice on how to proceed.

Comment: The citation i need to do is the one i put in the question, and the bibligraphy style i already say it that it was "alpha" when you ask me

Comment: Without switching to `biblatex` it isn't possible.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel so if i use biblatex, this can be done? can you explain some more?

Comment: @Dimitri: The option `maxalphanames` helps you. A similar question is here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27956/label-only-from-first-author/27958#27958

Comment: @Dimitri: I provided an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As written in the comments, without using `biblatex` it isn't possible. By using the package `biblatex` you have the options `minalphanames`/`maxalphanames`. The option `maxalphanames` requires a number and it represents the number of authors which will be counted for the label of the style `alphabetic`. In your case it should be 5.

Here a MWE with the correct compilation order using [`arara`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/arara/info)

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\listfiles
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{DBLP:journals/tit/HammonsKCSS94,  
  author    = {A. Roger Jr. Hammons  and
               P. Vijay Kumar and
               A. Robert Calderbank and
               Neil J. A. Sloane and
               Patrick Sol{\'e}},  
  title     = {The Z$_{\mbox{4}}$-linearity of Kerdock, Preparata, Goethals,
               and related codes},  
  journal   = {IEEE Transactions on Information Theory},  
  volume    = {40},  
  number    = {2},  
  year      = {1994},  
  pages     = {301-319},  
  ee        = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/18.312154},  
  bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}  
}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxnames=99,maxalphanames=5]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\verb+\cite{DBLP:journals/tit/HammonsKCSS94}+\cite{DBLP:journals/tit/HammonsKCSS94}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i already try with biblatex, but when i do, the references don´t appear...i don´t know why, can you give any idea?

Comment: Did you compile with `pdflatex`+`biber`+`pdflatex`? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I fix it, i think that was a problem with the compilation, but now is ok. Thanks again for the answer, that really help me, and besides you were the only one who really try to help me with my question