# Biber and traditional alpha citation style

Tags: biblatex, biber

Beacuse of Bibtex issues with UTF8 characters, I switched to using BibLaTex in conjunction with Biber. I installed the [biblatex-trad](http://get-software.net/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-trad/biblatex-trad.pdf) package to get traditional citation styles.

However, even by using the package, alpha stlye differes slightly from the original one.

This is my premable:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=trad-alpha]{biblatex}
\bibliography{tex/Bibliography}
```

And that is how I include it in my document:

```
 \printbibliography
```

The problem is how entries with many authors (like this one)

```
@InProceedings{lamere2003cmu,
  Title                    = {The CMU SPHINX-4 speech recognition system},
  Author                   = {Lamere, Paul and Kwok, Philip and Gouvea, Evandro and Raj, Bhiksha and Singh, Rita and Walker, William and Warmuth, Manfred and Wolf, Peter},
  Booktitle                = {IEEE Intl. Conf. on Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing (ICASSP 2003), Hong Kong},
  Year                     = {2003},
  Organization             = {Citeseer},
  Pages                    = {2--5},
  Volume                   = {1}
}
```

are rendered in the Bibliography.

Original:

[image: original]

Biber:

[image: the same entry with biber]

(Diffrence in fots doesn't matter; it is connected to different zoom levels)

**How to change trad-alha stye so that it uses the[XYZ+00] notation?**

Comment: Can you try something like `maxalphanames=3`?

Comment: Fine, would you agree that your question is essentially a duplicate of [Label only from first author](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27956/35864)?

Comment: Note that to get closer you might even want `\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{\textsuperscript{+}}`. Plus, one would probably have to make sure sentence casing applies only to some fields, but that is a whole other story. You should protect words that must remain capitalised though, as in `{The {CMU} {SPHINX-4} speech recognition system}` and `{{IEEE} Intl. Conf. on Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing ({ICASSP} 2003), {Hong Kong}},` see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864

Comment: Now that I see what the solution is yes, but maybe it is still good that the question is here because it is not so straight forward to think of that...

Comment: I will still vote to make your question a duplicate of the linked one, which does not mean that your question gets deleted, just that one is redirected to the other question that already has an answer, if you don't insist on me not doing so.

Comment: I don't have any problem with that.

Comment: Fine! It will be done, then.

Comment: See also https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-trad/issues/22, this is fixed in the github version of `biblatex-trad`.