# Bold numbers in List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, templates, bold

I'm having trouble modifying a template.  I need the numbers in my List of Figures (and tables) to be bolded so that it appears like

**Figure 1.1** instead of **Figure** 1.1

Here is the CLS file, but while, I can find where the List of Figures is generated (search for "%LIF IS HERE") nothing I do actually makes the numbers bold.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{ncsuthesis}[2012/01/26 v0.4 NC State ETD conformant thesis class]

\newcommand{\ncsu@thesistype}{phd}
\DeclareOption{phd}{\renewcommand{\ncsu@thesistype}{phd}}
\DeclareOption{ms}{\renewcommand{\ncsu@thesistype}{ms}}

%% Spacing options
\newcommand{\ncsu@defaultspacing}{\onehalfspacing}
\DeclareOption{singlespacing}{
     \renewcommand{\ncsu@defaultspacing}{\singlespacing}}
\DeclareOption{onehalfspacing}{
     \renewcommand{\ncsu@defaultspacing}{\onehalfspacing}}
\DeclareOption{doublespacing}{
     \renewcommand{\ncsu@defaultspacing}{\doublespacing}}

\newenvironment{lscape}{\begin{lscapenum}}{\end{lscapenum}}
\DeclareOption{hardcopy}{
    \renewenvironment{lscape}{\begin{lscapenotnum}}{\end{lscapenotnum}}
}

\DeclareOption{draft}{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}

\DeclareOption*{\PackageWarning{ncsuthesis}{Unknown option `\CurrentOption'. Ignoring}}
\ExecuteOptions{phd,onehalfspacing} % the default option is <phd, onehalfspacing>
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass[openany,oneside,titlepage,letterpaper]{book}

\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{hyphenat}
\RequirePackage{nolbreaks}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{sectsty}
\RequirePackage{tocloft}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % includes lof, lot, refs in toc
\RequirePackage{calc}

%% Capital letter height
\newlength{\ncsu@capitalheight}
\settoheight{\ncsu@capitalheight}{D}

%% Line height
\newlength{\ncsu@lineheight}
\setlength{\ncsu@lineheight}{2.0ex}

%% Leading height: The leading changes thoughout the document, so this
%%  length must be updated
\newlength{\ncsu@leading}

%% We must add two double spaces plus one capital-height (for the page number)
%%  to footskip.  Footskip is measured from the top of the bottom margin.
%%  (See geometry package documentation, note that includefoot option is used.)
\ncsu@defaultspacing
\newlength{\ncsu@footskip}
\setlength{\ncsu@footskip}{\ncsu@capitalheight}
\addtolength{\ncsu@footskip}{2\baselineskip}
\addtolength{\ncsu@footskip}{0.5ex}  % A little extra space to ensure there
                                     %  are 2 full double spaced lines
\RequirePackage[includefoot,
                margin=1in,
                lmargin=1.25in,
                bmargin=1.04in,
                footskip=\ncsu@footskip]{geometry}

%% Disposition format -- any titles, headings, section titles
\newcommand{\ncsu@dispositionformat}{}
\allsectionsfont{\ncsu@dispositionformat}
\providecommand{\dispositionformat}[1]{
    \renewcommand{\ncsu@dispositionformat}{#1}
    \allsectionsfont{\ncsu@dispositionformat}
}

%% Heading/Chapter/Section format
\newcommand{\ncsu@headingformat}{\ncsu@dispositionformat}
\providecommand{\headingformat}[1]{
    \renewcommand{\ncsu@headingformat}{\ncsu@dispositionformat #1}
}

%% \chapter*-to-first line space
%% This applies to preliminary headings, and ToC, LoF, LoT
\newlength{\ncsu@afterschapsep}
\setlength{\ncsu@afterschapsep}{3\ncsu@lineheight}

%% Headers/footers - page number
\pagestyle{plain}

%% Vertical space around tables and figures, triple spacing
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{3\ncsu@lineheight}
\setlength{\intextsep}{3\ncsu@lineheight}


%% Author name
\newcommand{\ncsu@authorfirstmiddle}{First Middle}
\newcommand{\ncsu@authorlast}{Last}

%% Command to test for period after middle name
\newboolean{@ncsu@needsperiod}
\newcommand{\ncsu@testlastchar}[2]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{\relax}}{
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{.}}{%
            \setboolean{@ncsu@needsperiod}{false}
        }{% #1 != .
            \setboolean{@ncsu@needsperiod}{true}
        }
        \let\next=\relax
    }
    {% #2 != relax
        \let\next=\ncsu@testlastchar
    }
    \next#2
}

\providecommand{\student}[2]{
    \renewcommand{\ncsu@authorfirstmiddle}{#1}
    \renewcommand{\ncsu@authorlast}{#2}
    \ncsu@testlastchar#1\relax
    \author{\ncsu@authorfirstmiddle{} \ncsu@authorlast}
}

%% Degree year - in case the degree year doesn't match the current year.
\newcommand{\ncsu@year}{\the\year}
\providecommand{\degreeyear}[1]{
    \renewcommand{\ncsu@year}{#1}
}

%% Thesis Title
\newcommand{\ncsu@thesistitle}{My Thesis Title}
\providecommand{\thesistitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\ncsu@thesistitle}{#1}}

\newlength{\ncsu@afterschapbeforeleadingsep}
\AtBeginDocument{% at begin doc is necessary since fncychap
                 %  redefines \@makeschapterhead
    \renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
        % Measure the leading here (which depends on the current line spacing),
        % and adjust the spacing accordingly between the baseline of the
        % heading and the top of capital letters on the first line.
        \setlength{\ncsu@leading}{\baselineskip-\ncsu@capitalheight}%
        \setlength{\ncsu@afterschapbeforeleadingsep}%
                  {\ncsu@afterschapsep-\ncsu@leading}%
        {\noindent\centering%
          {\ncsu@headingformat #1}%
          \par\nobreak%
          \vspace{\ncsu@afterschapbeforeleadingsep}}%
    }
}

\newcommand{\abstractname}{Abstract}
\newenvironment{abstract}{%
   \singlespacing
   \titlepage
   \chapter*{\abstractname}
   \noindent \MakeUppercase{\ncsu@authorlast{}, \ncsu@authorfirstmiddle{}}%
   \ifthenelse{\boolean{@ncsu@needsperiod}}{\@. }{~}%
    \nohyphens{\nolbreaks{\ncsu@thesistitle}.
   (Under the direction of
   \ifthenelse{\equal{\ncsu@chairtype}{chair}}%
              {\ncsu@chair}{\ncsu@cochairI\ and \ncsu@cochairII}.)}\\

   \ncsu@defaultspacing
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \pagestyle{empty}
}%
{\endtitlepage \pagestyle{plain}}


%% Abstract page commands
\newcommand{\makecopyrightpage}{
    \begin{titlepage}
    \centering
      \quad
      \vspace{0.47\textheight} %SPB

      \copyright{} Copyright \ncsu@year{} by \@author \\[1em]
      All Rights Reserved

      \vfill
    \end{titlepage}
}

%% Title page commands

\newcommand{\ncsu@committeesize}{4}
\providecommand{\committeesize}[1]{\renewcommand{\ncsu@committeesize}{#1}}

%% To allow for Chair vs Co-chairs:
\newcommand{\ncsu@chairtype}{}

\newcommand{\ncsu@chair}{Advisor Q. Chair}
\newcommand{\ncsu@chairtitle}{Chair of Advisory Committee}
\providecommand{\chair}[2][]{
    \renewcommand{\ncsu@chair}{#2}
    % Checking if optional title argument is present.
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\renewcommand{\ncsu@chairtitle}{#1}}
    % Declare that we have a chair:
    \renewcommand{\ncsu@chairtype}{chair}
}

\newcommand{\ncsu@cochairI}{Co-chair 1 of Committee}
\newcommand{\ncsu@cochairItitle}{Co-chair of Advisory Committee}
\providecommand{\cochairI}[2][]{
    \renewcommand{\ncsu@cochairI}{#2}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\renewcommand{\ncsu@cochairItitle}{#1}}
    % Declare that we have co-chairs.
    \renewcommand{\ncsu@chairtype}{cochair}
}

\newcommand{\ncsu@cochairII}{Co-chair 2 of Committee}
\newcommand{\ncsu@cochairIItitle}{Co-chair of Advisory Committee}
\providecommand{\cochairII}[2][]{
    \renewcommand{\ncsu@cochairII}{#2}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\renewcommand{\ncsu@cochairIItitle}{#1}}
    \renewcommand{\ncsu@chairtype}{cochair}
}

\newcommand{\ncsu@memberI}{Member 1 of Committee}
\newcommand{\ncsu@memberItitle}{}
\providecommand{\memberI}[2][]{
    \renewcommand{\ncsu@memberI}{#2}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\renewcommand{\ncsu@memberItitle}{#1}}
}

\newcommand{\ncsu@memberII}{Member 2 of Committee}
\newcommand{\ncsu@memberIItitle}{}
\providecommand{\memberII}[2][]{
    \renewcommand{\ncsu@memberII}{#2}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\renewcommand{\ncsu@memberIItitle}{#1}}
}

\newcommand{\ncsu@memberIII}{Member 3 of Committee}
\newcommand{\ncsu@memberIIItitle}{}
\providecommand{\memberIII}[2][]{
    \renewcommand{\ncsu@memberIII}{#2}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\renewcommand{\ncsu@memberIIItitle}{#1}}
}

\newcommand{\ncsu@memberIV}{Member 4 of Committee}
\newcommand{\ncsu@memberIVtitle}{}
\providecommand{\memberIV}[2][]{
    \renewcommand{\ncsu@memberIV}{#2}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\renewcommand{\ncsu@memberIVtitle}{#1}}
}


\newcommand{\ncsu@titlepageparagraph}{
 \ifthenelse{\equal{\ncsu@thesistype}{phd}}{
   A dissertation submitted to the Graduate Faculty of\\
   North Carolina State University\\
   in partial fulfillment of the\\
   requirements for the Degree of\\
   Doctor of Philosophy   
 }{} % end ifthenels phd
 \ifthenelse{\equal{\ncsu@thesistype}{ms}}{
   A thesis submitted to the Graduate Faculty of\\
   North Carolina State University\\
   in partial fulfillment of the\\
   requirements for the Degree of\\
   Master of Science
 }{} % end ifthenels phd
}

\newcommand{\ncsu@program}{Degree Program}
\providecommand{\program}[1]{\renewcommand{\ncsu@program}{#1}}

\newcommand{\ncsu@citystate}{Raleigh, North Carolina}

\newcommand{\ncsu@signatureline}[2][]{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
     \hrule
     \vspace{0.5ex}
     #2\\ #1
    \end{minipage}
}

\newcommand{\ncsu@committeesignatures}{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\ncsu@chairtype}{chair}}{
    \ifthenelse{\ncsu@committeesize=3}{
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c@{\hspace{0.5in}}c}
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberItitle]{\ncsu@memberI} &
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberIItitle]{\ncsu@memberII} \\[6em]
         \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@chairtitle]{\ncsu@chair}}
      \end{tabular}
    }{} % end ifthenelse = 3
    \ifthenelse{\ncsu@committeesize=4}{
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c@{\hspace{0.5in}}c}
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberItitle]{\ncsu@memberI} &
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberIItitle]{\ncsu@memberII} \\[6em]
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberIIItitle]{\ncsu@memberIII} &
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@chairtitle]{\ncsu@chair} \\
      \end{tabular}
    }{} % end ifthenelse = 4
    \ifthenelse{\ncsu@committeesize=5}{
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c@{\hspace{0.5in}}c}
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberItitle]{\ncsu@memberI} &
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberIItitle]{\ncsu@memberII} \\[5em]
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberIIItitle]{\ncsu@memberIII} &
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberIVtitle]{\ncsu@memberIV} \\[5em]
         \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@chairtitle]{\ncsu@chair}}
      \end{tabular}
    }{} % end ifthenelse = 5
    \ifthenelse{\ncsu@committeesize=6}{
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c@{\hspace{0.5in}}c}
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberItitle]{\ncsu@memberI} &
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberIItitle]{\ncsu@memberII} \\[5em]
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberIIItitle]{\ncsu@memberIII} &
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberIVtitle]{\ncsu@memberIV} \\[5em]
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberVtitle]{\ncsu@memberV} &
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@chairtitle]{\ncsu@chair} \\
      \end{tabular}
    }{} % end ifthenelse = 6
  }{} % end ifthenelse type = chair
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\ncsu@chairtype}{cochair}}{
    % co-chairs; if number is odd, put co-chairs on top line.
    \ifthenelse{\ncsu@committeesize=3}{
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c@{\hspace{0.5in}}c}
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@cochairItitle]{\ncsu@cochairI} &
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@cochairIItitle]{\ncsu@cochairII} \\[6em]
         \multicolumn{2}{c}%
           {\ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberItitle]{\ncsu@memberI}}
      \end{tabular}
    }{} % end ifthenelse = 3
    \ifthenelse{\ncsu@committeesize=4}{
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c@{\hspace{0.5in}}c}
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberItitle]{\ncsu@memberI} &
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberIItitle]{\ncsu@memberII} \\[6em]
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@cochairItitle]{\ncsu@cochairI} &
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@cochairIItitle]{\ncsu@cochairII}
      \end{tabular}
    }{} % end ifthenelse = 4
    \ifthenelse{\ncsu@committeesize=5}{
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c@{\hspace{0.5in}}c}
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@cochairItitle]{\ncsu@cochairI} &
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@cochairIItitle]{\ncsu@cochairII} \\[5em]
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberItitle]{\ncsu@memberI} &
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberIItitle]{\ncsu@memberII} \\[5em]
         \multicolumn{2}{c}%
           {\ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberIIItitle]{\ncsu@memberIII}}
      \end{tabular}
    }{} % end ifthenelse = 5
    \ifthenelse{\ncsu@committeesize=6}{
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c@{\hspace{0.5in}}c}
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberItitle]{\ncsu@memberI} &
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberIItitle]{\ncsu@memberII} \\[5em]
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberIIItitle]{\ncsu@memberIII} &
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@memberIVtitle]{\ncsu@memberIV} \\[5em]
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@cochairItitle]{\ncsu@cochairI} &
         \ncsu@signatureline[\ncsu@cochairIItitle]{\ncsu@cochairII} \\
      \end{tabular}
    }{} % end ifthenelse = 6
  }{} % end ifthenelse type = cochair
}

\newcommand{\maketitlepage}{
     \thispagestyle{empty}
     \clearpage
     \singlespacing
      \begin{center}
            \vfill
        \ncsu@thesistitle
            \vfill
        by \\
        \@author
            \vfill
       \ncsu@titlepageparagraph 
            \vfill
       \ncsu@program\\[1\ncsu@lineheight]
           \vfill
       \ncsu@citystate\\[1\ncsu@lineheight]
       \ncsu@year
           \vfill
       APPROVED BY:
           \vfill
       \ncsu@committeesignatures
      \end{center}
     \clearpage
     \ncsu@defaultspacing
}

%%  Template
\newcommand{\ncsu@dedbioack}[1]{%
    \chapter*{#1}%
}

%%  Dedication
\newcommand{\dedicationtitle}{Dedication}
\newenvironment{dedication}
{\ncsu@dedbioack{\dedicationtitle}}
{\clearpage}

%%  Biography
\newcommand{\biographytitle}{Biography}
\newenvironment{biography}
{\ncsu@dedbioack{\biographytitle}}
{\clearpage}

%%  Acknowledgements
\newcommand{\acknowledgementstitle}{Acknowledgements}
\newenvironment{acknowledgements}
{\ncsu@dedbioack{\acknowledgementstitle}}
{\clearpage}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\settowidth{\cftchapnumwidth}{\textbf{Chapter 00}}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\newcommand{\thesistableofcontents}{%
    \singlespacing%
    \setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\ncsu@leading}{\baselineskip-\ncsu@capitalheight}%
    \setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}%
              {\ncsu@afterschapsep-\cftbeforechapskip-\ncsu@leading}%
    \tableofcontents%
    \clearpage%
    \ncsu@defaultspacing%
}
%% tocloft typesets ToC title, so we must give it our heading formats
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\ncsu@headingformat}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}

%\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of Figures} 
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES} %SPB
\settowidth{\cftfignumwidth}{Figure 00.000}

\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\textbf{Figure }}%LIF IS HERE
\newcommand{\thesislistoffigures}{%
    \singlespacing%
    \setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\cftfigindent}{.01in} %SPB
    \setlength{\ncsu@leading}{\baselineskip-\ncsu@capitalheight}%
    \setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}%
              {\ncsu@afterschapsep-\cftbeforechapskip-\ncsu@leading}%
    \listoffigures%
    \clearpage%
    \ncsu@defaultspacing%
}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\ncsu@headingformat}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}

%\renewcommand{\listtablename}{List of Tables} SPB
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES} %SPB
\settowidth{\cfttabnumwidth}{Table 00.000}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Table }
\newcommand{\thesislistoftables}{%
    \singlespacing%
    \setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{-\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\cfttabindent}{.01in} %SPB
    \setlength{\ncsu@leading}{\baselineskip-\ncsu@capitalheight}%
    \setlength{\cftafterlottitleskip}%
              {\ncsu@afterschapsep-\cftbeforechapskip-\ncsu@leading}%
    \listoftables%
    \clearpage%
    \ncsu@defaultspacing%
}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\ncsu@headingformat}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}

%%  Loading pdflscape package for page rotation
\RequirePackage{pdflscape}
%%  Loading fancyhdr package to change page numbering
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
%%  Loading sideways for sideways environment
\RequirePackage{rotating}

\newlength{\portraittextheight}
\setlength{\portraittextheight}{\textheight}
\addtolength{\portraittextheight}{\footskip}
\newlength{\portraittextwidth}
\setlength{\portraittextwidth}{\textwidth}

\RequirePackage{afterpage}
\RequirePackage{changepage}

%% Rotate page and page number
\newenvironment{lscapenum}
{
%%   The syntax of the \changepage command is
%% \changepage{textheight}{textwidth}{evensidemargin}{oddsidemargin}{columnsep}
%%            {topmargin}{headheight}{headsep}{footskip}
   \clearpage
   \changepage{\ncsu@footskip}{-\ncsu@footskip}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
   \begin{landscape}
     \pagestyle{fancy}
     \fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
     \fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
     \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
     \rfoot{
       \setlength{\unitlength}{\portraittextheight}
       \begin{picture}(0,0)
           \put(0.055,0.557){\begin{sideways}\thepage\end{sideways}} % page number
       \end{picture}
     }

}
{
   \end{landscape}
   \addtolength{\textheight}{-\ncsu@footskip}

   \global\@colht=\textheight
   \global\vsize=\textheight
   \global\@colroom=\textheight

   \pagestyle{plain}
}

\newenvironment{lscapenotnum}
{
   \begin{landscape}
}
{
   \end{landscape}
}

\RequirePackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{colon}{:\hspace{0.8em}}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
%% natbib redefines \thebibliography, so we add our own requirements
%% at \begin{document} time.
\AtBeginDocument{
    \let\ncsu@thebibliography\thebibliography
    \let\endncsu@thebibliography\endthebibliography
    \renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
    {
        \doublespacing %%modification 12/12/13 by isbayram@ncsu.edu, Grad School requires double spacing in the references
        \begin{ncsu@thebibliography}{#1}
    }
    {
        \end{ncsu@thebibliography}
        \ncsu@defaultspacing
    }
}

\newlength{\appendixwidth}
\settowidth{\appendixwidth}{Appendix A}
\addtolength{\appendixwidth}{1em}
\providecommand{\appendixheader}[1]{
    \renewcommand{\ncsu@appendixheader}{#1}
}

%% Count the total number of appendices
\RequirePackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{chapter} % chapter counter is used for appendices

\AtBeginDocument{%

\newcounter{ncsu@appendixtocdepth}
\ifthenelse{\c@tocdepth > 2}
{\setcounter{ncsu@appendixtocdepth}{2}}
{\setcounter{ncsu@appendixtocdepth}{\c@tocdepth}}

\let\ncsu@appendix\appendix
\renewcommand{\appendix}{
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\ncsu@appendixheader}}
    % Appendix title page heading not defined, define it
    {
        \ifthenelse{\totvalue{chapter} = 1 }%
        %% number of appendices = 1
        {\newcommand{\ncsu@appendixheader}{APPENDIX}}
        %% number of appendices > 1
        {\newcommand{\ncsu@appendixheader}{APPENDICES}}
    }
    % Appendix title page heading already defined, do nothing
    {}

    \chapter*{\ncsu@appendixheader} %% insert 'Appendix' titlepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\ncsu@appendixheader}
    %% Adding "Appendix" before letter in TOC
    %%  We must change the width of the box which the appendix letter is set in
    %%  and add the "Appendix " before the letter.  See tocloft documentation.
    \addtocontents{toc}{
        \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{Appendix }
        \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapnumwidth}{\protect\appendixwidth}
        \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapfont}{\protect\cftsecfont}
        \protect\setlength{\protect\cftbeforechapskip}{\protect\cftbeforesecskip}
        \protect\setlength{\protect\cftchapindent}{\protect\cftsecindent}
        \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappagefont}{\protect\cftchapfont}
        \protect\setlength{\protect\cftsecindent}{\protect\cftsubsecindent}
        \protect\addtolength{\protect\cftsubsecindent}{\cftsecnumwidth}
        \protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{\c@ncsu@appendixtocdepth}
    }
    \clearpage
    \ncsu@appendix %% call internal \appendix macro
} % \renewcommand{appendix}
} % \AtBeginDocument

\ncsu@defaultspacing
%% 
%% Copyright (C) 2009-2012 by Josh Hykes <jmhykes@ncsu.edu> and others
%% 
%% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License (LPPL), either
%% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any later
%% version.  The latest version of this license is in the file:
%% 
%% http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% 
%% This work is "maintained" (as per LPPL maintenance status).
%% 
%% This work consists of the file  ncsuthesis.dtx
%% and the derived files           ncsuthesis.ins,
%%                                 ncsuthesis.pdf and
%%                                 ncsuthesis.cls.
%% 
%%
%% End of file `ncsuthesis.cls'.
```

A reduced version of my .tex file looks like this.  Can anyone help me?

```
\documentclass[12pt,          % font size: 11pt or 12pt
               phd,           % degree:    ms or phd
               onehalfspacing % spacing: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
               ]{ncsuthesis}

\usepackage{booktabs}  % professionally typeset tables
\usepackage{amsmath}%,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{textcomp}  % better copyright sign, among other things
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}    % filler text
\usepackage{subfig}    % composite figures
\usepackage{clrscode3e}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}


%%%%%%%%%%% Hack for alphanumeric bibliography
\RequirePackage[
            style=alphabetic,%numeric-comp,%authoryear-comp,%
            sorting=nyt,%ynt                    
            hyperref=true, %    
            firstinits=true,%
            backend=bibtex,
            natbib=true,
            url=false,
            isbn=false,
            maxnames=2, %for et al to be used
            maxalphanames=1, %to avoid printing a + for every et al in the abbreviation
            doi=false]{biblatex}        


%needed to do et al after two names
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44048/use-et-al-in-biblatex-custom-style
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}

%Simplify abbreviation (the default uses either one or two authors and it indicates et al with a +)
%The following five lines make it so that only the first author is used in the abbreviation
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27956/label-only-from-first-author
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}
    \renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{}
    \DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{in={}}
    \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{in={}}
    \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
    \DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

%\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}} %authoryear          
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\makeatletter

\newrobustcmd*{\parentexttrack}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \blx@bibopenparen#1\blx@bibcloseparen
  \endgroup}

\AtEveryCite{%
  \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}

\makeatother
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\parencite{#1}}


\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{language}}

\addbibresource{dissertation.bib}

 \defbibheading{myheading}[BIBLIOGRAPHY]{
 \chapter*{#1}
 \markboth{#1}{#1}}

\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{verbatim}% multiline commenting
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{balance} 
\usepackage{graphicx} %eps figures can be used instead
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[format=plain,justification=RaggedRight,singlelinecheck=false,font=small,labelfont=normal,labelsep=space]{caption} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{abbrevs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify{\DateMark} % after having loaded abbrevs

\usepackage{units} %Needed to solve bug from citation Hydrodynamics in 21/2 dimensions
%see http://www.latex-community.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=989

\usepackage[sharp]{easylist} %used for brainstorming purposes 
%\usepackage{mathabx} % used for \Asterisk for convolution %conflicts with \widering

%compile on single pass
%\usepackage[backend=biber,...]{biblatex}



%%%Fancy tables
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94032/fancy-tables-in-latex
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\newcolumntype{L}{@{}>{\kern\tabcolsep}l<{\kern\tabcolsep}}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% Hack for containing figures within sections
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%http://ctan.org/pkg/placeins
\usepackage{placeins}
%De­fines a \FloatBar­rier com­mand, be­yond which floats may not pass; use­ful, for ex­am­ple, to en­sure all floats for a sec­tion ap­pear be­fore the next \sec­tion com­mand.

\dispositionformat{\bfseries}            % bold and serif

\headingformat{\large\MakeUppercase}   % All letters uppercase
\frenchspacing


\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}



\student{John M.}{Smith} % a middle initial

%% Degree program
\program{Computer Science}

\thesistitle{A North Carolina State University Sample \LaTeX{} Thesis \break 
with a Title So Long it Needs a Line Break}



%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%%---------------------------- Personal Macros -------------------------------%%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------%%

%% A few examples to get you started.
\newcommand{\uv}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{\hat{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\bo}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{\Omega}}}
\newcommand{\eref}[1]{Eq.~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\fref}[1]{Fig.~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\tref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\del}{\nabla}
\renewcommand{\exp}[1]{e^{#1}}
\newcommand{\Conv}{\mathop{\scalebox{1.5}{\raisebox{-0.2ex}{$\ast$}}}}%


\usepackage{color}
%\newcommand{\NEW}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\NEW}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\COMMENT}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}


\newcommand{\NOTER}[1]{\textcolor{orange}{#1}}
\newcommand{\NOTEC}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\NOTEK}[1]{\textcolor{magenta}{#1}}

\newcommand{\mum}{\ensuremath{{\mu}\text{m}}}

%This makes it so that you can add short paths in your .tex by including the folders where you store your images in the search path
\graphicspath{{./Chapter-1/figs/}{./Chapter-2/figs/}{./Chapter-3/figs/}}%{./Chapter-4/figs/}{./Chapter-5/figs/}{./Chapter-6/figs/}}


%%---------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
\usepackage{calc}
%% Capital letter height
\newlength{\chaptercapitalheight}
\settoheight{\chaptercapitalheight}{D}
\newlength{\chapterfootskip}
\setlength{\chapterfootskip}{\chaptercapitalheight}
\addtolength{\chapterfootskip}{2\baselineskip}
\addtolength{\chapterfootskip}{0.5ex}  % A little extra space to ensure there are 2 full double spaced lines
%\def\chapterfootskipnum{\chapterfootskip}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}

%\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\centering\ncsu@headingformat}


%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47184/height-of-figure-caption-textheight
\newlength\graphht
\newcommand\calculategraphicstargetheight[1]{%
     \setlength\graphht{\textheight 
                       -\parskip
                       -\abovecaptionskip -\belowcaptionskip
                       -(12pt * #1) % assuming baselineskip of 12pt in caption
                       -\chapterfootskip
                       }}

%\usepackage{titlesec}

%landscape support in fancyhdr from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9071/how-to-translate-and-rotate-the-heading-of-landscaped-pages
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\fancypagestyle{lscapedplain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot{%
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
      \node[outer sep=1cm,above,rotate=90] at (current page.east) {\thepage};}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\frontmatter

\include{front}

\mainmatter


\pagestyle{fancy}
\newgeometry{margin=1in,lmargin=1.25in,footskip=\chapterfootskip, includehead, includefoot}
\include{Chapter-1/Chapter-1}



\begin{spacing}{1}
 \setlength\bibitemsep{11pt} %22pt = 2*11pt, where fontsize is 11pt
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{{\uppercase{\bibname}}} %\textorpdfstring and \uppercase needed due to hyperref package http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=16601
 %\vspace{-0.5in}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bf\filcenter
}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{11pt}{\bf\filcenter}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-0.5in-9pt}{22pt}

\printbibliography[heading=myheading]
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add the following to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\bfseries Figure }
```

The above code lets the font change (to **bold**) run through to the end of the figure number within the LoF, rather than have it remain with only the word **`Figure`**.

The following is a recreation of the solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\bfseries Figure }
\settowidth{\cftfignumwidth}{Figure 00.0000}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}

\end{document}
```